# Starting Explorer with UNC Path Argument That Contains Comma Fails To Open Folder

Tags: c#, windows, explorer, processstartinfo

Passing in a value with a comma in the UNC path (e.g. "\servername\Smith,John\Documents\") causes the following to start windows explorer but it opens the My Documents instead of the folder path. If I paste in the path into windows explorer's address bar, the folder opens appropriately.

```
public void OpenWindowsExplorer(string path) {
        var runExplorer = new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = "explorer.exe", Arguments = path };
        Process.Start(runExplorer);
    }
```

Any idea as to why this is happening/how to resolve the issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put quotes around the path:

```
public void OpenWindowsExplorer(string path) {
    path = string.Format("\"{0}\"", path);
    var runExplorer = new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = "explorer.exe",
                                             Arguments = path };
    Process.Start(runExplorer);
}
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks Daniel!

Comment: Sorry... got called into a meeting.